# trying to calculate specific cells of tables with javascript without the use of id's

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate cell 2 and cell 3 of the table on every row in which the result will show in cell 4 and cell 4 will be multiplied by 1.96 in order to calculate cell 5

```
function Calculate()
{
    let calc = document.getElementById("tblCalc").querySelectorAll("tr");
    rows.cells [4] = rows[1,2,3,4,5].cells[3].value/1000*cells[2].value;
    rows.cells [5] = rows[1,2,3,4,5].cells[4].value*1.96;
    for (var i = 0 < calc.rows.cells; i++; )
    {
        
        document.getElementById("result1").value;
    document.getElementById("result2").value = document.getElementById("result1").value*1.96;
        
    }
```

here is 1 part of my html

```
        <table id="tblCalc">
        <tr>
            <th>Ingredient</th>
            <th>Prijs per kilo</th>
            <th>Nodig voor de 25cm pizza in gram</th>
            <th>25cm pizza</th>
            <th>35cm pizza</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td><input type="number"></td>
            <td><input type="number"> </td>
            <td><input type="number" readonly></td>
            <td><input type="number" readonly></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" ></td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td><input type="text" ></td>
            <td><input type="text" readonly></td>
            <td><input type="text" readonly></td>
        </tr>

<input type="number" readonly id="result1">
    <br>
    <input type="number" readonly id="result2">
    <br>
    <button onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: (there are more tr and td i just gave a small part of it cause i couldn't get everything on it without the site giving me errors.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please fix your code to (minimal reproducible example)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example] to help you with your problem properly.